# How to eliminate audio output

Tags: audio, pi-4

After installing a webcam, and configuring sound and video, I see that my system considers that I have 2 analog audio devices (seen by VLC). One works and the other doesn't when I'm listening to music. My problem is that my Chromium browser is using the wrong audio device. Question: how to remove it? or direct the audio stream from the browser to the correct one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, during the installation of the web-cam it was necessary to install "Audio Pulse", and this was a problem because the system took it by default. I uninstall "Audio Pulse" and the sound is OK with VLC and my browsers.
Now, I have to go deeper with the sound of my web-cam.
If this experience can help ...

Comment: Please mark the answer as the accepted one with a click on the tick on its left side. That prevents your Question from being shown as an unsolved Post to the community and saves them/us a lot of work.